# Left outer join now working linq object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have two tables which i want to link via `left outer join`. Why the below query is returning me this error?

> "linq query object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
IEnumerable<RoadTrafficCount> roadTrafficCounts =
    _unitOfWork.RoadTrafficCountRepository
        .Get(i => i.ThanaID == thanaid && i.RoadID == roadid, includeProperties: "VehicleList, VehicleList.VehicleType");

IEnumerable<VehicleList> vehicleLists = _unitOfWork.VehicleListRepository.Get();

var q = (from pd in vehicleLists
         join od in roadTrafficCounts
         on pd.VehiID equals od.VehiID
         into t
         from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
         orderby pd.VehiID
         select new
         {
             Id=(int?)rt.Id,
             ThanaId=(int?)rt.ThanaID,
             RoadID = (int?)rt.RoadID,
             pd.VehiID,
             pd.VehicleName,
             pd.VehiDescription,
             rt.CountHatDay,
             rt.CountNonHatDay
         }).ToList();
```

I have attached the table Design.How can i solve this ?

[image: Table design picture]

---

**Update**: I have tried [Tim's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36883394/284240) using the conditional operator to avoid accesssing a property on a null reference. But i still get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rt` will be `null` if the `VehiID` of `RoadTrafficCount` doesn't exist in `VehicleListRepository`. Then you get the exception on `(int?)rt.Id`, `(int?)rt.RoadID` and so on.

You can use the conditional operator to check if it's `null`:

```
... 
select new
{
    Id =            rt == null ? (int?)null : rt.Id,
    ThanaId =       rt == null ? (int?)null : rt.ThanaID,
    RoadID =        rt == null ? (int?)null : rt.RoadID,
    pd.VehiID,
    pd.VehicleName,
    pd.VehiDescription,
    rt.CountHatDay =     rt == null ? (int?)null : rt.CountHatDay,
    rt.CountNonHatDay =  rt == null ? (int?)null : rt.CountNonHatDay
})
....
```

Comment: yes when rt get null it throw the exception but i have tried according to you but still it shows error. I have add a Error picture on the start of the question. Could you please review.

Comment: @Muhammad.NazmulAhsan: have you verified that nothing is `null`, for example `roadTrafficCounts`?

Comment: @Muhammad.NazmulAhsan: you're not using my code. Look at  your initialization of `CountHatDay` and `CountNonHatDay` where you still access the null refernece `rt` directly.

Comment: i need to cast the CounthatDat short when i cast that to short it shows 
"anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name" . And my re sharper change that to Add explicit name. that;s why the code not looks like yours

Comment: i have tried but they say you have to earn 15 reputation..:(

Comment: Thanks again you for extra help.